# HOWTO Discover Postgres Running in Windows Environment

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell

**HOWTO Discover Postgres Running in Windows Environment**

So How do we discover all the Postgres installed in our Windows 2012R2/2016 environment with PowerShell?

I wrote this script but I am told that will not find ALL postgres instances, if the install was not coded to create a service... Ideas?

```
#List-PostGres-Servers.ps1
Remove-Item -force "drive\path\*-List-PostGres-Servers-log.txt" -ErrorAction 
ignore
$today = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)+"-"+(get-date -uformat %H)
Start-Transcript -Path "drive\path\$today-List-PostGres-Servers-log.txt"
$servers = get-content 'drive\path\input\listofservers.txt'
foreach ($server in $servers){
if ((Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName $server -quiet) -eq $false){continue}
else{
$PostGresSearch = (get-service -ComputerName $server -name *postgres* -ErrorAction Ignore -WarningAction Ignore -InformationAction Continue)
$PostGresServicename = $PostGresSearch.Name 
#|out-file -Encoding ascii "drive\path\output\DOMAINNAME-CheckListPostgres.txt" -force -Append
if ($PostGresServicename -eq $null){continue}
else {
$server+","+" "+$PostGresServicename
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check to see if postgres is currently running with:

```
Get-Process *postgres*
```

In the case where neither a service is installed nor is the binary running, then you're not using that postgres install. Alternatively, search `$env:ProgramFiles` or `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` for `psql`.

Comment: No, this is to look for a postgres task, if it exists at all; a positive, not a negative.